# CentOS MAKEDEV Install

Tags: centos

I'm trying to build a clean CentOS 7 image (with full Kernel, BIOS, and MBR) on a new block device.  My dev machine is Centos6 but I can also work with Centos7.  Following some guides I found online they invoke the following command:

`/sbin/MAKEDEV -d /mnt/ec2-image/dev -x console`

However I do not have the MAKEDEV tool installed (and it is not in the base yum repos).  I found some documents that mentioned udev may replace MAKEDEV, is this so?  Is there a new tool that can accomplish the same thing?

Comment: `MAKEDEV` is in the CentOS 6 base repository but does not appear to be in the CentOS 7 repositories. I don't know, offhand, what replaced it.

Comment: It looks like `mknod` might be the replacement.

Comment: `mknod` does look like it has similar capabilities but my understanding of linux devices and the two tools isn't enough to figure out how to map commands in `MAKEDEV` to `mknod`.  I will just use a manually downloaded and installed centos6 version of `MAKEDEV` in the meantime.